# phpStorm doesn't transpile some scss files to css

Tags: sass, phpstorm

I don't know why my filewatcher doesn't transpile certain scss files. I wanted to rename files that already existed to use them as partials. That worked fine for most of them but i couldn't rename all of them. When I tried to use "refactor->rename" there was a warning that the files would be used by another script but that was definitly not the case. I was not able to rename them in phpStorm so i renamed them in the directory manually. That worked but now no css files are created anymore. I tried to synchronize but that didn't help. My settings seems to be correct (see picture). Anyone had the same problem before and knows the solution?

[image]

Comment: You have **"Track only root files"** option enabled. With that option turned ON all partials (that are included in "master"/root files) will not have separate .css file as compiled content already will be in master file.

Comment: Thx! You we're right - the content of the partial is already in the main file. Didn't recognize that before. With disabling the "Track only root files" there still wont be created css files but that doesn't matter as long as the transpiled content is within the main file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When "Track only root files" option is on, the content of partials is merged into a single .css files when transpiling, so that a single css is generated instead of creating a separate css for each partial

Comment: Thats not entirely correct. It ignores the files with this prefix "_" like _footer.scss